# CS-Cart Ajax response to div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cs-cart

CS-Cart ajax is working fine, I am also getting response but how can I use this response with html/js on my view(checkout.tpl) file.

Controller (front-end) :  send_sms.php

```
use Tygh\Registry;
use Services_Twilio;
use Tygh\Ajax;

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

 if ($mode == 'send_sms') {

    $status = 1;
    $response = array(
        'status' =>$status,
        'data' =>'Hello World',
    );

   if($status == 1) {
        fn_set_notification('N', fn_get_lang_var('success'), fn_get_lang_var('sms_sent'), true);
    } else {
        fn_set_notification('E', fn_get_lang_var('warning'), fn_get_lang_var('sms_failed'), true);

    }

    $val=json_encode($response);

    Registry::get('ajax')->assign('result', $val);

 }
 exit;
}
```

View checkout.tpl (design/themes/responsive/templates/views/checkout/checkout.tpl)

```html
<div id="result">
    <!-- id="result" -->
    <!-- result -->
</div>
<h2>Verify your number</h2>

<form class="cm-ajax" action="index.php" method="post" name="send_sms">


    <input type="hidden" name="result_ids" value="result" />

    <div class="form-control send_sms_block">
        <input type="text" name="country_code" id="country_code" disabled value="+92"/>
        <input type="text" name="carrier_code" id="carrier_code" disabled value="300"/>
        <i class="ty-icon-down-micro open_cr"></i>
        <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone"/>

        <div class="carrier_list hidden">
            <ul>
                <li>301</li>
                <li>302</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <input class="ty-btn ty-btn__big" id="send_sms" type="submit" value="Send Pin" name="dispatch[send_sms.send_sms]"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following solution:

php file:

```php
use Tygh\Registry;
use Services_Twilio;
use Tygh\Ajax;

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

 if ($mode == 'send_sms') {

    $status = 1;
    $response = array(
        'status' =>$status,
        'data' =>'Hello World',
    );

   if($status == 1) {
        fn_set_notification('N', fn_get_lang_var('success'), fn_get_lang_var('sms_sent'), true);
    } else {
        fn_set_notification('E', fn_get_lang_var('warning'), fn_get_lang_var('sms_failed'), true);

    }

    $val=json_encode($response);

    Registry::get('view')->assign('result', $val);
    Registry::get('view')->display('views/path/to/tpl/file.tpl');
 }
 exit;
}
```

tpl file:

```html
<div id="result">
{if $result}{$result}{/if}
<!--result--></div>

<h2>Verify your number</h2>

<form class="cm-ajax" action="index.php" method="post" name="send_sms">


    <input type="hidden" name="result_ids" value="result" />

    <div class="form-control send_sms_block">
        <input type="text" name="country_code" id="country_code" disabled value="+92"/>
        <input type="text" name="carrier_code" id="carrier_code" disabled value="300"/>
        <i class="ty-icon-down-micro open_cr"></i>
        <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone"/>

        <div class="carrier_list hidden">
            <ul>
                <li>301</li>
                <li>302</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <input class="ty-btn ty-btn__big" id="send_sms" type="submit" value="Send Pin" name="dispatch[send_sms.send_sms]"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please replace on **send_sms.php**

```
$val=json_encode($response);
Registry::get('ajax')->assign('result', $val);
```

with

`echo '<div id="result">'.json_encode($response).'</div>';`

Comment: A better option in cs-cart context is 
        `Registry::get('ajax')->assignHtml('result' . (empty($_REQUEST['additional_id']) ? '' : '_' . $_REQUEST['additional_id']), json_encode($response));`

It will just print content in my #result div but suppose how can I alert or other thing by js once ajax request complete.